# Basic results for chi square processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, textbook-recommendation

I could not find any introductory material with basic results regarding chi-square processes. Their definition from [The Supremum of Chi-Square Processes](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11009-013-9331-1)
is as a sum of $d$ squares of independent Gaussian processes.

I'm looking for results such as large deviations, first passage time, etc.